# Send jpg image from ANDROID to servlet

Tags: android, servlets, servlet-3.0

I am making an Instagram like application for my college project.

CLIENT = Android
SERVER = Servlet

I want to send an image from android to servlet. I just need the image send and revive code. I have figured out the rest.

Thank you for help.

Comment: You should convert your image into Base64 string send Via Webservice to Sevrlet store in DB, and then decode that base64 into Image on View side !! I hope this will help you !!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert your image into Base64 string send Via Webservice to Sevrlet store in DB, and then decode that base64 into Image on View side !!
I hope this will help you !!

Comment: Thanks and Happy Coding !!